# React Native Too Many Re-renders Error with Java SDK Real-time Data for GPU-Accelerated Curve Plotting

Tags: android, react-native, plot, real-time

I'm working on a React Native application that integrates a Java SDK for real-time data visualization. The aim is to create a real-time graph curve. However, I'm encountering a 'too many re-renders' error, likely due to the high volume of data that React Native struggles to handle efficiently.

I've attempted to address this issue by exploring methods to optimize rendering. My initial thought is to leverage GPU acceleration using HTML canvas, as commonly done in basic web applications. However, I'm uncertain about the compatibility and best practices for implementing this in a React Native context.

I tried reducing the render count by sending data in groups rather than individually. However, this resulted in suboptimal fluidity and did not meet the real-time requirements.

I explored drawing the plot using SVG paths to optimize the rendering process. While this approach showed promise, the 'Too Many Re-renders' error persisted, and the performance was not optimal.

Another approach involved using a WebView to draw the plot. Despite this attempt, the rendering issues persisted, and the real-time aspect was not achieved.

I'm now seeking advice on alternative strategies or optimizations that can be employed to overcome the 'Too Many Re-renders' error in React Native, particularly when dealing with a substantial amount of real-time data. Additionally, insights into leveraging GPU for rendering in a React Native context would be highly valuable.